# StreamWriter - Process cannot access the file because it is being used by another process

Tags: powershell

I am trying to rewrite an `Add-Content` script as a `StreamWriter` version, reason being that the file is ~140 MB and `Add-Content` is far too slow.

This is my `Add-Content` version, which loops through each row until it can find a header row starting `FILE|` and creates a new file with a filename of the second delimited (by pipe) value in that row.  The `Add-Content` works as intended, but is really slow.  It takes 35-40 mins to do it:

```
Param(
    [string]$filepath = "\\fileserver01\Transfer",
    [string]$filename = "sourcedata.txt"
)

$Path = $filepath
$InputFile = (Join-Path $Path $filename)
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)

while (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if ($Line -match 'FILE\|([^\|]+)') {
        $OutputFile = "$($matches[1]).txt"
    }
    Add-Content (Join-Path $Path $OutputFile) $Line
}
```

I've researched that `StreamWriter` should be faster. Here is my attempt, but I get the error

> The process cannot access the file '\fileserver01\Transfer\datafile1.txt' because it is being used by another process.

```
Param(
    [string]$filepath = "\\fileserver01\Transfer",
    [string]$filename = "sourcedata.txt"
)

$Path = $filepath
$InputFile = (Join-Path $Path $filename)
$Reader = New-Object System.IO.StreamReader($InputFile)

while (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if ($Line -match 'FILE\|([^\|]+)') {
        $OutputFile = "$($matches[1])"
    }
    $sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter (Join-Path $Path $OutputFile)
    $sw.WriteLine($line)
}
```

I assume it's something to do with using it in my loop.

Sample data:

```
FILE|datafile1|25/04/17
25044|0001|37339|10380|TT75
25045|0001|37339|10398|TT75
25046|0001|78711|15940|TT75
FILE|datafile2|25/04/17
25047|0001|98745|11263|TT75
25048|0001|96960|13011|TT84
FILE|datafile3|25/04/17
25074|0001|57585|13639|TT84
25075|0001|59036|10495|TT84
FILE|datafile4|25/04/17
25076|0001|75844|13956|TT84
25077|0001|17430|01111|TT84
```

Desired outcome is 1 file per `FILE|` heade row using the second delimited value as the file name.

Comment: Hi, shouldn't `$sw = New-Object System.IO.StreamWriter (Join-Path $Path $OutputFile)` be *before* the while loop, not *inside* it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're creating the writer *inside* the `while` loop without ever closing it, thus your code is trying to re-open the already opened output file with every iteration. Close an existing writer and open a new one whenever your filename changes:

```
while (($Line = $Reader.ReadLine()) -ne $null) {
    if ($Line -match 'FILE\|([^\|]+)') {
        if ($sw) { $sw.Close(); $sw.Dispose() }
        $sw = New-Object IO.StreamWriter (Join-Path $Path $matches[1])
    }
    $sw.WriteLine($line)
}
if ($sw) { $sw.Close(); $sw.Dispose() }
```

Note that this assumes that you won't open the same file twice. If the same output file can appear multiple times in the input file you need to open the file for appending. In that case replace

```
$sw = New-Object IO.StreamWriter (Join-Path $Path $matches[1])
```

with

```
$sw = [IO.File]::AppendText((Join-Path $Path $matches[1]))
```

Note also that the code doesn't do any error handling (e.g. input file doesn't begin with a `FILE|...` line, input file is empty, etc.). You may want to change that.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.  Putting the write before loop runs the script, however does not mimic the `Add-Content` behaviour.  It just writes the entire contents after the first time it hits `FILE|` and ignores other header rows starting `FILE|`. Any ideas on why?